# Problem with the speed of mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb

I have a csv file ( name : members ) that contains 20,000 IDs and a mongodb BSON collection ( name : Customers ) that contains 40 million rows of data and with ID , phone_Number , etc columns.

what I want to do is that I want to search for those 20,000 IDs ( name : user id ) that are available in that 40-million-rowed database ( name : id ) and if so, I want to return the ID and the phone-Number. Here is mongodb query that I am currently using:

```
db.getCollection("Customers").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                "Customers" : "$$ROOT"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : { 
                "localField" : "Customers.id", 
                "from" : "members", 
                "foreignField" : "user id", 
                "as" : "members"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$unwind" : { 
                "path" : "$members", 
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "Customers.id" : "$Customers.id", 
                "Customers.phone" : "$Customers.phone", 
                "_id" : NumberInt(0)
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
);
```

I am not so familiar with mongodb and the problem is that this query took 5 hours till now and still is not giving any output.

Is there any suggestions for me to get the result  as fast as possible?
Is there any ways to speedup query's performance?
Do you suggest any other query codes for this job?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you create indexes on the fields you are querying?

Comment: yes sir, I created indexes on Customers.id and Customers.phone-Number and Both together and members.[user id]. but a question just popped into my head: Does Just "creating" an index enough? or should I do other  stuff to get it envolved in the query process?

Comment: You might try the `explain` command to see if it is using an index.

Comment: @Joe yes sir, it was using indexes

Comment: @Joe I was just curious, if we want to force a query to use some indexes, is there any commands or codes to write?

Comment: Take a look at `hint`